# Access State and Methods from Parent Class within Child Class in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got a child-class and a parent-class in ReactJS. I want my child to access the state of the parent, which is beeing updated every millisecond. Also it should be possible for the child to access some parents methods.

### Parent:

```
interface StatesZeit{
        datum : Date;
    }

    export default class StoppUhr extends React.Component<undefined, StatesZeit>{
        uhrID : number;

        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                datum : new Date(0),
            };
            this.start = this.start.bind(this);
            this.stopp = this.stopp.bind(this);
            this.counter = this.counter.bind(this);
        }

        start() {
            this.uhrID = setInterval(() => {
                this.counter();
            }, 0);
        }

        stopp() {
            clearInterval(this.uhrID);
        }

        counter() {
            this.setState({
                datum : new Date()
            });
        }

        render(){ // Returns the Child and passes the states as properties
            return (
                <ZeitManager stopp={this.stopp.bind(this)}
                             start={this.start.bind(this)}
                             counter={this.counter.bind(this)}
                             timeState={this.state.datum}/>
            )
        }
    }
```

### Child

```
export interface PropsZM {
    timeState : Date;
    start(); // not sure if correct, should somehow reference functions of parent
    stopp();// not sure if correct, should somehow reference functions of parent
    counter();// not sure if correct, should somehow reference functions of parent
}

export class ZeitManager extends React.Component<PropsZM, undefined>{
    private _millisec : number;

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.startManager = this.startManager.bind(this);
        this.stoppManager = this.stoppManager.bind(this);
    }

    startManager() {
        this.props.start();
    }

    stoppManager() {
        this.props.stopp();
        this._millisec = this.props.timeState.getMilliseconds();
    }

    counterManager() {
        this.props.counter;
    }

    get millisec(): number {
        return this._millisec;
    }

    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.start}</div>;
    }

}
```

In another class i am initializing a child-object and call the funtion startManager() on it. But then i get an error message saying *Cannot read property 'start' of undefined*. I am new to React and I think that i am doing something wrong here in defining the properties of the child. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here. thanks

Comment: How are you "initializing a child-object"?

Comment: Within the contructor of another class. Like contructor () { super(); this.zeitmanager = new Zeitmanager() }
Then i call the functions on zm object. Like zm.startManager()

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate your components like that, you need React to do that for you only then will the whole props/state thing work.

You can use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
zm = React.createElement(ZeitManager);
```

Or get a reference to the instance:

```
function useZeitManager(instance: ZeitManager) {
    // do what ever with it
}

export default class StoppUhr extends React.Component<undefined, StatesZeit>{
    ...

   render() {
      return (
         <ZeitManager 
            ref={ el => useZeitManager(el) }
            stopp={ this.stopp.bind(this) }
            start={ this.start.bind(this) }
            counter={ this.counter.bind(this) }
            timeState={ this.state.datum } />
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, how would i use this ref from another class?

Comment: Depends on who the classes interact with each other and your overall design. I just added the `useZeitManager` function, but you can use a method of an existing instance instead